# Show that if $23a^2 ≡ b^2 \pmod {17}$ then $23a^2 ≡ b^2 \pmod {289}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was trying to solve this question from a Number Theory Previous Exam, ended up getting the incorrect answer, but in going through the following proof there are a few ideas I'm still struggling to understand:

Proof:
We calculate The Legendre Symbol:

$(23/17) = (6/17)=(3/17)=(17/3)=(2/3) =-1$

Up to here all is fine

So if $23a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod {17}$ then we claim $17 \mid a$, else we would have
$23 \equiv (ba^{−1})^2 \pmod{17}$
which is a contradiction to the above calculation. So $17^2 \mid 23a^2 = b^2$ and so $17 \mid b$. Then
$17^2\mid 23a^2 − b^2$
so $23a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod {289}$.

The two parts of the proof I'm confused about are the following:

1. How does the claim that $17\mid a$ save us from the possibility  $23 \equiv (ba^{−1})^2 \pmod{17}$?
2. The other bit I am confused about is why exactly we were able also to conclude that $17^2 \mid 23a^2$ as well?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $a\equiv 0 \pmod {17}\implies b\equiv 0 \pmod {17}$.

Comment: Answer to 1): since $17\mid a$, there is no $a^{-1}$. Answer to 2): since $17\mid a$, $17^2\mid a^2$. But you should replace your "$= b^2$" by $\equiv b^2\pmod{17}$.

Answer (score 1):

1. If $17|a$ then $a^2\equiv 0\pmod{17}$ and $a^2\equiv 0\pmod{289}$ as well. Because of the equation
   $$23a^2\equiv b^2\pmod{17},$$
   we also have that $b^2\equiv 0\pmod{17}$, so $b\equiv 0\pmod{17}$ and $b^2\equiv 0\pmod{289}$ as well. Hence, the equation
   $$23a^2\equiv b^2\pmod{289}$$
   is satisfied since $0\equiv 0\pmod{289}$.
2. $17|a \iff 17^2|a^2$ as Anne said in the comments. I used this idea in 1 repeatedly.